# SQL query to get count based differnt condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Description of table columns -

TYPE : VARCHAR

STATUS : VARCHAR

ORDER_DATE : TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE

Please find the below table structure and required output.

In the required result -

0TO30DAYS : Count of Type for previous 30 days

30TO60DAYS : Count of Type for previous 31 to 60 Days

60TO90DAYS : Count of type for 61 to 90 Days

Please note that I'm using Oracle DB unable to create three different count columns as per the different date range. Please let me know how to create SQL for the same in ORACLE.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` ignores `null`, so you could `count` a `case` expression with your logic:

```
SELECT   type,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN day_diff BETWEEN 0 AND 31 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
           AS "0TO30DAYS",
         COUNT(CASE WHEN day_diff BETWEEN 31 AND 61 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
           AS "30TO60DAYS",
         COUNT(CASE WHEN day_diff BETWEEN 61 AND 91 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
           AS "60TO90DAYS"
FROM     (SELECT type, CAST (order_date AS DATE) - SYSDATE AS day_diff
          FROM   my_table)
GROUP BY type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TYPE,
       CASE
         WHEN order_date >= (SYSDATE - 30) AND order_date < SYSDATE THEN
          COUNT(TYPE)
       END AS count30,
       CASE
         WHEN order_date >= (SYSDATE - 60) AND order_date < (SYSDATE - 30) THEN
          COUNT(TYPE)
       END AS count60,
       CASE
         WHEN order_date >= (SYSDATE - 90) AND order_date < (SYSDATE - 60) THEN
          COUNT(TYPE)
       END AS count90
  FROM TABLE
 GROUP BY TYPE, order_date
```